# Threads operating on the one instance of a method

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex

I'm creating an app, where I have 50x50 map. On this map I can add dots, which are new instances of the class "dot". Every dot has it's own thread, and every thread connected with a specific dot operates on the method "explore" of the class, and in this method there is another method "check_place(x,y)" which is responsible for checking if some place on the map was already discovered. If not, the static variable of the class "num_discovered" should be incremented. This single instance of the method "check_place(x,y)" should be accessed in the real-time by every thread started in the app.

Constructor:

```
public dot(Form1 F)
{    
    /...
    thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(explore)); //wątek wykonujący metodę explore klasy robot
    thread.Start();
}
```

check_place(x,y) method:

```
static void check_place(int x, int y)
{
    lock (ob)
    {
        if (discovered[x, y] == false)
        {
            discovered[x, y] = true;
            num_discovered += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

In the explore method I'm invoking method "check_place(x,y)" like this:

```
dot.check_place(x, y);
```

Is it enough to achieve a situation where in the single time only one dot can check if place was already discovered?

Comment: Is your question whether the `discovered[x, y]` and `num_discovered` access is thread-safe? We'd need to see the declaration of `ob` for that.

Comment: Why do you have one thread for each dot? I can imagine this to be useful if you have a low number of dots, each dot takes a lot of processing power, and it is critical that that your app runs in realtime. It's also fine if it's a practice project to learn about threads. Otherwise, this sounds like maintainability hell to me.

Comment: Won't there be contention between threads when they're all calling check_place ? Why do you need have a thread for each dot ?

Comment: It's just practice project, so It has to be that. The declaration of "ob" is simple: static object ob = new object()

Comment: I mean it's unclear what your actual question is.

Comment: During the app running, and dots movement only one dot can check if the place where it is was discovered or not using it's thread. So there cannot be contention between threads to access that method. Only one thread can access method "check_place(x,y)" in a specific time.

Comment: That's not what "contention" means in terms of multi-threading; if there is more than one thread that **wants** to check it at the same time, then there is contention. A `lock` changes that from contention that results in an error to contention that results in the program going slower (because threads have to wait on each other). In cases where threads are mostly out of each others way that's good (the wait only happens briefly at key interaction points), in cases where threads are constantly waiting on other threads you're probably more efficient to just use one thread.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So the "lock" structure is properly used when I want threads to wait on each other in access to that method?

Comment: It's correct but bad. I'll give more info in an answer.

Comment: You'll never ever need to juggle 2500 threads in practice, I can assure you of that. It's a complete waste of resources. Especially given that you pretty much serialize 100% of the code - no two threads will ever be able to execute `check_place` at the same time. I don't really see any practical experience you could get from this "practice project". Why not try something a bit more interesting, like partitioning the locking spaces and allocating the different work tasks on a limited number of threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it enough to achieve a situation where in the single time only one dot can check if place was already discovered?

Yes. But what's the point?

If threads are spending all of their time waiting on other threads, what have you gained from being multi-threaded?

There are three (sometimes overlapping) reasons to spawn more threads:

1. To make use of more than one core at the same time: overall throughput increases.
2. To have work done while another thread is waiting on something else (typically I/O from file, DB or network): overall throughput increases.
3. To respond to user interaction while work is being done: overall throughput decreases, but it feels faster to the user as they are separately being reacted to.

Here the last doesn't apply.

If your "checking" involved I/O then the second might apply, and this strategy might make sense.

The first could well apply, but because all the threads are spending most of their time waiting on other threads, you don't gain an improvement in throughput.

Indeed, because there is overhead involved in setting up threads and switching between them, this code will be slower than just having one thread do everything: If only one thread can work at a time, then only have one thread!

So your use of a lock here is correct in that it prevents corruption and errors, but pointless in that it makes everything too slow.

What to do about this:

If your real case involves I/O or other reasons why the threads in fact spend most of their time out of each others' way, then what you have is fine.

Otherwise you've got two options.

Easy: Just use one thread.
Hard: Have finer locking.

One way to have finer locking would be to do double-checking:

```
static void check_place(int x, int y)
{
  if (!discovered[x, y])
    lock (ob)
      if (!discovered[x, y])
      {
        discovered[x, y] = true;
        num_discovered += 1;
      }
}
```

Now at the very least some threads will skip past some cases where `discovered[x, y]` is `true` without holding up the other threads.

This is useful when a thread is going to get a result at the end of the locked period. Its still not good enough here though, because it's just going to move on quickly to a case were it fights for the lock again.

If our lookup of `discovered` were itself thread-safe and that thread-safety was finely grained, then we could make some progress:

```
static void check_place(int x, int y)
{
  if (discovered.SetIfFalse(x, y))
    Interlocked.Increment(ref num_discovered)
}
```

So far though we've just moved the problem around; how do we make `SetIfFalse` thread-safe without using a single lock and causing the same problem?

There are a few approaches. We could use striped locks, or low-locking concurrent collections.

It seem that you have a fixed-size structure of 50×50, in which case this isn't too hard:

```
private class DotMap
{
  //ints because we can't use interlocked with bools
  private int[][] _map = new int[50][];
  public DotMap()
  {
    for(var i = 0; i != 50; ++i)
      _map[i] = new int[50];
  }
  public bool SetIfFalse(int x, int y)
  {
    return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _map[x][y], 1, 0) == 0;
  }
}
```

Now our advantages are:

1. All of our locking is much lower-level (but note that `Interlocked` operations will still slow down in the face of contention, albeit not as much as `lock`).
2. Much of our locking is out of the way of other locking. Specifically, that in `SetIfFalse` can allow for separate areas to be checked without being in each others way at all.

This is neither a panacea though (such approaches still suffer in the face of contention, and also bring their own costs) nor easy to generalise to other cases (changing `SetIfFalse` to something that does anything more than check and change that single value is not easy). It's still quite likely that even on a machine with a lot of cores this would be slower than the single-threaded approach.

Another possibility is to not have `SetIfFalse` thread-safe at all, but to ensure that the threads where each partitioned from each other so that they were never going to hit the same values **and** that the structure is safe in the case of such multi-threaded access (fixed arrays of elements above machine word-size are thread-safe when threads only ever hit different indices, must mutable structures where one can `Add` and/or `Remove` are not).

In all, you've got the right idea about how to use `lock` to keep threads from causing errors, and that is the approach to use 98% of the time when something lends itself well to multithreading because it involves threads waiting on something else. Your example though hits that lock too much to benefit from multiple cores, and creating code that does is not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Your performance on this could potentially be pretty bad - I recommend using Task.Run here to increase efficiency when you need to run your explore method on multiple threads in parallel.

As far as locking and thread safety, if the lock in check_place is the only place you're setting bools in the discovered variable and setting the num_discovered variable, the existing code will work.  If you start setting them from somewhere else in the code, you will need to use locks there as well.

Also, when reading from these variables, you should read these values into local variables inside other locks using the same lock object to maintain thread safety here as well.

I have other suggestions but those are the two most basic things you need here.

Comment: How is `Task.Run` going to increase efficiency?

Comment: Yeah, instead of creating a new thread each time, Task.Run uses an internally managed thread pool, creating threads on demand only if they are needed.  This is much more efficient.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: But the threads are all blocking on the same lock, so the thread pool is going to have to create more threads, so "on demand" results in the same number of threads, which is equally inefficient.

Comment: You're wrong.  Read the first sentence in the link I included in my last comment.  It reads like this "Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool and returns a task handle for that work."

Comment: And this affects what I say, how?

Comment: Notice the word "queues" and the word "ThreadPool" - the work is queued on the threadpool which has a max size by default.  If the max size is reached, the queued actions will not result in the creation of more threads.  Instead, since these actions are queued, they will not be executed until the threadpool size drops below the max and more threads are made available.  Read up on threadpooling.

Comment: I don't have any more time to spend explaining this to you, sorry.

Comment: Pooling is not going to solve the problem of contention causing completely serialised operation. That serialisation means that its already acting like a threadpool with a maximum size of `1`. When you've a maximum concurrency level on an operation then pooling only has a real effect if its maximum pool size is greater than `1` and less than that maximum. There is no number greater than `1` and less than `1`.

Comment: It's a better solution to a different problem. One thread at a time is one thread at a time. Threadpools are not magic wands. And yes, you got two upvotes so you've mislead two people.

Comment: Look at the code the questioner provided again.  Notice that he calls "explore" when creating the thread but the lock occurs in "check_place".  He mentions that explore calls check_place but this is clearly a different method that could be doing other things as well.  So explore could be doing a variety of things before and after the lock you're focused on.  Surely you can't be saying that the presence of a lock in check_place will cause parallel invocations of explore to run in a serial manner?